# how to prevent stretched vertical shadow in blob shadow which projected by Projector of Unity

Tags: unity, shadows

I feel it's a ridiculous because projector's rotation of X is 90.

the projector is a orthographic.

how can i prevent that long stretch shadow in vertical side of a platform?

[image]

Comment: Which stretched shadow do you mean?

Comment: a black shade that right below the car.